# Jquery select original matched element after modi

Tags: jquery

I need to access to the #foo matched elements after I used the find method, 
I read in a book months ago the method name but I can't find it anywhere,

```
$("#foo").find("img").css("height", "20px").method().html()
```

basically the "method" returns the jquery chain to the #foo matched elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`end()` method?

[jQuery end()](https://api.jquery.com/end/)
`Description: End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.`

For your case:

```
$("#foo").find("img").css("height", "20px").end().html()
```

Comment: YES :D I was about to think I imagined that method thanks